# Destroying micro posts on Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everyone, I know there have been a few inquiries on this topic already, but none of the other answers have solved my problem. I'm trying to complete the "destroying micro posts" section of the tutorial, and get the following error on the spec tests:

> Micropost pages micropost destruction as correct user should delete a
>   micropost

```
 Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
 SyntaxError:
   /Users/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
   ...ethod: :delete, data { confirm: "You sure?" }, title: feed_i...
   ...                               ^
   /Users/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
   ... data { confirm: "You sure?" }, title: feed_item.content );@...
   ...                               ^
 # ./app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb___2425863304392027210_70358052260580'
 # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__3111465487832718441_70358084930700'
 # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:38:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I've spent the last 7 hours trying to figure this out. Can't find the mistake.

```
#Micropost_pages_spec.rb:

require 'spec_helper'

describe "Micropost pages" do

subject { page }

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }

describe "micropost creation" do
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do

        it "should not create a micropost" do
            expect { click_button "Post" }.not_to change(Micropost, :count)
        end

        describe "error messages" do
            before { click_button "Post" }
            it { should have_content('error') }
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

        before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
        it "should create a micropost" do
            expect { click_button "Post" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
end

describe "micropost destruction" do
    before { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user) }

    describe "as correct user" do
        before { visit root_path }

        it "should delete a micropost" do
            expect { click_link "delete" }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(-1)
        end
    end
end
```

end

```
#microposts_controller.rb:

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
      if @micropost.save
          flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
          redirect_to root_url
      else
          @feed_items = []
          render 'static_pages/home'
      end
  end

  def destroy
      @micropost.destroy
      redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

  def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
  end

  def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end
end


#_feed_item.html.erb:

<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
    <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete, data { confirm: "You sure?" }, title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>


#_micropost.html.erb

<li>
    <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
    <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, title: micropost.content %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: `data { confirm: "You sure?" }` you're missing the `:` after `data`.

Comment: Thank you so much sevenseacat. You rock!